# We chat sdk in ios: getting 3 errors with libWeChatSDK_armv7_armv7s.a file

Tags: ios, ios8, wechat

I am not able to compile my code with newer version of lib file ie "libWeChatSDK_armv7_armv7s.a"

Please provide me solution. Also sample code to send message to particular single contact.

Comment: You need to post the error message. You will get better assistance if your question is more precise.

Comment: ld: warning: ignoring file /libWeChatSDK.a, missing required architecture x86_64 in file /libWeChatSDK.a (3 slices)
ld: warning: ignoring file /TestWeChat/libWeChatSDK_armv7_armv7s.a, missing required architecture x86_64 in file ibWeChatSDK_armv7_armv7s.a (3 slices)
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SendMessageToWXReq", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in ViewController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_WXApi", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in ViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your build setting is wrong.

Your project's "Valid Architecture" includes "x86_64", but wechat library can't support this architecture.

Why? I think your project's "Supported Platforms" is wrong. It should be iOS, not Mac.